# How to set laravel file permissions inside a docker image

Tags: laravel, docker, chmod, chown

I have the following dockerfile to build my Laravel web application. After I run it I get permission errors when trying to acccess the **vendor** and **storage** directories. My question is what is the correct way of setting permissions for Laravel for a php:7.2-fpm base image. The error I receive is:

> fopen(/var/www/app/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-normal_4ced20531a4f462a8c5c535d4debd2eb.ufm):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    npm

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs 

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy existing application directory contents

COPY . /var/www/app

RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/app
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/app/vendor
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/app/storage

# COPY --from=nodeBuild ./ /var/www
RUN composer install
RUN npm install
RUN npm update

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: How are you running the image?  What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Just updated with the error message. I should add if I give the vendor directory 777 permissions it works fine. But there must be a 'right' way of doing this

Answer (score -1):

I removed these commands:

```
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/app
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/app/vendor
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/app/storage
```

I got the webserver to own the directory recursively:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

This resolved the problem